# past simple or present in this case

Tags: past-simple

Is it possible to write

> I wanted to know if you **are going** to...

Or shall I say

> I wanted to know if you **were going** to...

in the case the event is still to happen.

Comment: Your situation indicates a decision will be made (whether or not to go to ...). Normally, if no decision is expected to have been made yet, then "I wanted to know if you *are going* to..." is best. If a decision possibly has already been made, then "I wanted to know if you *were going* to...". The second one is more natural when you expect a "no".

Answer (score 1):

The apparent ambiguity here stems from the idiomatic use of the simple past *I wanted to* in reference to the present.

It is idiomatic in English to say (not to write formally, n.b.) *I wanted* or *I only wanted* of desires in the present. Renaat Declerc, in [*Tense in English: lts Structure and Use in Discourse,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yPwWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=declerck%20%2221.2%20Tentativeness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiopdLavLXPAhUDGz4KHQz2C_4Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=declerck%20%2221.2%20Tentativeness%22&f=false) (1991:78) writes:

> **21.2 Tentativeness**
>
> With some verbs (*wonder, expect, hope, want, think,* etc.) the past tense is used to render a statement less direct, more tentative, hence more tactful, polite:
>
> (a) I *wanted* to ask you a question.
>     (b) I *wondered* if you heard anything in the grapevine...
>     (c) I *was hoping* that you would be able to help me tomorrow.
>      (...)

It is common to hear a question *in the present* expressed as something like:

> Hi, it's Dave. I wanted to know if you are going to have dinner with me.

Thus, in this case, when we know that event has not taken place, the *idiomatic* choice is the simple present, preceded by either the present or preterite form of the verb *want:*

> I **want** to know if you **are** going to...
>   I **wanted** to know if you **are** going to...

Answer (score 1):

If the event is still to happen, meaning you are *not* talking about a past event, the use of the past tense forms  of both *want* and *be going* are used for politeness or another type of 'hesitation'. If you want to speak more directly, use the presente tense forms.

Thus, you can say

> I wanted to know if you are going to Miami next Friday.

polite use of *want*

> I wanted to know if you were going to Miami next Friday.

polite use of both *want* and *be going*.

Answer (score -1):

If the event is still to happen, meaning it may or may not happen, or that the event hasn't happened yet, then you would use the second sentence.

> I wanted to know if you **were going** to...

Using this subjunctive tense also specifies doubt that the person is going.=

Comment: The event is sure to happen but it is not now in this case

Comment: Updated answer.